# Android BottomNavigation setting its background to some alfa, shows rectangle inside

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When I try to set the `backgroundColor` to either from `resource` colors or by `Color(0x44000000)` inside the `BottomNavigation` bar strange rectangle is present. Could anyone explain why?

[image]

My code:

```kotlin
    @Composable
    fun Root() {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        Scaffold(
            bottomBar = {
                BottomNavigation(backgroundColor = Color(0x44000000)) {
                    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                    val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
                    screens.forEach { screen ->
                        BottomNavigationItem(
                            icon = { Icon(screen.icon, contentDescription = null) },
                            label = { Text(text = screen.label) },
                            selected = currentRoute?.let{it == screen.route} ?: false,
                            onClick = {
                                navController.navigate(screen.route){
                                    popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id){
                                        saveState = true
                                    }
                                    launchSingleTop = true
                                    restoreState = true
                                }
    
                            })
    
                    }
                }
            }
        ) {
            RootNavGraph(navController = navController)
        }
```

Comment: That's an artifact from the elevation shadow drawn behind it, which you can see 'cause the background is translucent. If you don't really need the shadow, you can just set the elevation to zero.

Comment: How can I set the 0 elevation, using modifiers, or do you have an exact example?

Comment: I was hoping you weren't gonna ask me that. :-) It'll be a parameter, like `backgroundColor`, but I can't find a `BottomNavigation` Composable anywhere, so I'm not sure what its parameters are. Your IDE should be able to show you the list if you hover over `BottomNavigation`. Look for the one named `elevation` and see what its type is; possibly something like `BottomNavigationElevation`.

Comment: The parameter to control the `BottomNavigation` elevation is called `elevation` and expect a value in `DP`. As Mike said, using 0 elevation will solve this problem (default value when not specified is 8):  `BottomNavigation(backgroundColor = Color(0x44000000), elevation = 0.dp) { }`. You can see docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#BottomNavigation(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,kotlin.Function1)).

Comment: Hah, that's why I am asking because I am not able to find anything related to elevation even in the IDE.

Comment: Did you get it working, though, with @ThalesIsidoro's suggestion? This is the hover list I was referring to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUrdc.png. My issue was that I just had the wrong project open. Duh.

Comment: Yes I got it guys many thanks to both of you, the elevation did the thing. :)